# Parallel programming in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am learning parallel programming in Haskell recently. I have imported the parallel library into my code. My data volume is large enough (up to 500 million). I specify different threads to run on the GHC platform. However, **the more threads, the more The running time is longer**, what is the problem, is the amount of data not large enough? Or is my own parallel environment not configured correctly?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gs3s2.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH0Rq.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngY40.png

Comment: This is unfortunately a fairly common experience. Parallel programming in Haskell _should_ be easy and reliably boost performance, but in practice memory / thunks etc. often get in the way. — Please include all relevant information in the question as text, don't use screenshots or otherwise images.

Comment: Sorry for my experiment results I only keep screenshots because the running time is too long. I used 2 billion data today and still the same effect. Is there any way to improve the parallel computing efficiency of multi-threading?

Comment: How is that a reason for not including your source code and results in text format?

Comment: Your example is a really bad case of parallelization scenario, meaning more time would be lost on communication between cores than performing actual computation on each function call. You're basically trying to recursively add a list. Why? By the time the computation starts, it's already done. It would make much more sense to split your list into, say, 5 parts of a million each (you' re not really working with lists for this amount of data, are you?), perform `sum` on each of them in parallel (5 cores) and sum the results.

Comment: If you're interested in actually parallelizing a function of the kind `map (really_heavy_function) [list_of_elements]`, where every list element will be assigned to a different core, and work on it for a while, I'd be happy to give you my working solution, if you're actually still fiddling with the subject. Tried it recently and it works like a charm on 4 core Raspberry Pi, and it changed my mind. Parallelization in Haskell is really easy, even though I had to read up on it for a week first. The Haskell way I guess?